# Ng2 Smart Table set selected item in filter list

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm using ng2-smart-table and I want my 'status' column to select a specific item in the filter list. Normally the selectText is selected as it is the first option but i want 'Test2' to be selected, is this possible?

```
status: {
  title: 'Status',
  filter: {
    type: 'list',
    config: {
      selectText: 'Select',
      list: [
        { value: 'Test', title: 'Test' },
        { value: 'Test1', title: 'Test1' },
        { value: 'Test2', title: 'Test2', selected: true },
        { value: 'Test3', title: 'Test3' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```